# What whitespace symbols does Winmerge use for line endings (EOF and EOL)?

Tags: line-endings, winmerge

If I select View Whitespace from the view menu of WinMerge, line-ending symbols are displayed.  One file has been changed, but I can't find any documentation on what symbols represent what characters.

No idea what this pair of symbols signifies, this is the file before line-ending conversion to CR/LF:

[image: Before]

This symbol seems represent the CR/LF pair, as I converted the file to have those line endings:

[image: After]

To add some more context, Visual Studio detected that this file had mixed line endings, and converted them to CR/LF.  Then I looked at the differences to the original file stored in git.  So gits line-ending conversion may have some interaction here in the way it converts the original file.  My line endings are for automatically changing to windows line endings.

Comment: Can't tell you about that, but I can tell you that WinMerge uses the same symbol (¤, circle with four lines coming off of it) for CR, LF, or CRLF, whatever the default line ending is for the file. You can set the line endings with File->Convert Line Endings To, which only shows up when you are comparing files and click on one of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WinMerge 2.14.0.0 Unicode (and probably other versions as well) has a setting under menu://edit/options/Editor "preserve original EOL characters".

- When "preserve original EOL characters" is checked WinMerge shows `§¶` for some files and `¶` for others<sup>1</sup>.
- When "preserve original EOL characters" is unchecked, WinMerge shows `¤`.
  Note: unchecked "preserve original EOL characters" can cause WinMerge to mark two files, that appear identical, as having differences on every line.

Using a hexeditor shows that:

- 0x0d a.k.a. `<cr>` is shown as `§`; and
- 0x0a a.k.a. `<lf>` is shown as `¶`.

---

<sup>1</sup> <sub>Suspected problems with line endings in my repository led me to [OP's question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41233131/814206); therefore I have both `§¶` and `¶`.</sub>